# How do quickly switch dagster from running with test data and the full data?

Tags: dagster

I have a Dagster project where I like to test it with a small subset of data (eg. I run it daily with a list of 10,000 users). This is helpful at catching issues before kicking of a "big" job.

Currently I have a software defined asset called `userIds` which I modify between runs:

```py
@asset
def userIds():
    userIds = get_user_ids_from_database()
    # return userIds
    return userIds[:10_000]
```

But this is probably not how it should be done.

What is the best way to switch the config of an asset in Dagster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [configuration docs](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/configuration/config-schema). The gist is that you can provide a configuration schema which defines variables that you can enter values for when launching a run. In your case it might look something like this:

```py
from dagster import Field, asset

@asset(config_schema={"number_of_users": Field(int, is_required=False)})
def userIds(context):
    userIds = get_user_ids_from_database()
    # return userIds
    number_of_users = context.op_config.get("number_of_users")
    if number_of_users:
        return userIds[:number_of_users]
    else:
        return userIds
```

(note: the `context` variable is injected for you by the Dagster framework if you define it as the first parameter to your op/asset)

The configuration can then be provided in any of the contexts in which you might run the asset ([these execution docs](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/configuration/config-schema#specifying-runtime-configuration) have some examples of providing runtime configuration via config schemas). For instance, in this case you might execute the asset programmatically like this:

```py
from dagster import materialize

asset_result = materialize(
    [userIds],
    run_config={
        "ops": {"userIds": {"config": {"number_of_users": 10000}}}
    },
)
```